# Program detecting OS and aborting installation

Tags: wine

I have installed wine 7.0.1 on my Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit PC. I was looking forward to install Autotune using wine. But when I try installing, It starts installing and then says "The operating system is not adequate for running this program. Aborting installation". And this problem occurs for other programs also. How do I fix this?

Comment: Thanks for adding release details, what architecture are you using?  as most of wine is designed for *amd64* or *i386* but Ubuntu is made for many architectures (*more than wine was created for*).

Comment: @guiveric Sorry...really in a hurry. Just did it now.